# Can I set AWS credentials on a Spring Boot/Cloud @SqsListener? (Java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

Double newbie here, to both SQS and Spring Cloud.  I've created (using the console) an SQS queue.  The company wiki I'm working from says then to generate temporary credentials, which come out looking like this:

```
aws_access_key_id = <secret>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret>
region = us-west-2
aws_session_token = <secret and VERY LONG, like 240 characters>
```

NOTE:  more on that "aws_session_token" later.

So, once I have done that, I can send a message from the CLI, like this.

```
`aws --endpoint-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/99999999999999/<queue name>.fifo sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/99999999999999/<queue name>.fifo --message-body "cli test msg 2" --message-group-id "azgroup"`
```

So far so good.  But now, I want to implement an SqsListener to listen continuously.  So, I checked out the code here https://github.com/sixthpoint/spring-boot-sqs-fifo-tutorial, which is a minimal Spring Cloud SQS application, and set all the configs as shown in the readme.  My listener, right now, looks simply like this:

```
@SqsListener(value=SQSURL)
public void process(String json) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("here");
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

But, when I try to start the application up, I get this error:

`com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID:....)`

I *think* what's going on is that at startup, the listener is trying to contact my queue, and is being rejected because it's not sending that aws_session_token.  (The company wiki, again, says this: "You will see aws_session_token. This is something you have not had before. It is required for your key to work!")

So, is there a way to explicitly set my AWS parameters, either in the Java code where the @SqsListener is defined, or somewhere in configs, such that the aws_session_token gets passed?  It doesn't seem possible to pass an AwsCredentials object.  (edit) And it doesn't seem that that would help me anyway, since AwsCredentials doesn't contain that field.

Or . . . is there some other way of solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Answering, or at least partially answering, my own question:  It turns out that the aws_session_token is required when, and only when, using temporary aws credentials, which as I noted is what I've been given to work with.  It has to be added to any CLI operations, but there is no way to set it the AwsCredentials object in Java code.  So that's not going to help me.  It may just not be possible to connect from Java code when using temporary credentials.  If I'm wrong and there is a way, please let me know.